# DRF Serializer Field return value different from value saved to database

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

How can I create a custom Serializer Field that returns a value different from the value saved to the database?

For example:

- Database currently has the value `['alpha', 'bravo', 'delta']`
- It's updated with the value `['alpha', 'delta', 'E']`
- Field should save `['alpha', 'delta', 'echo']` to the database and run a delete function on `'bravo'`
- Field should return `['alpha', 'delta', {'foo': 'E', 'bar': 'echo'}]` in the 201 response (but not in 200 responses)

Essentially, I'm looking for a method in the custom Field I can write my logic with two inputs (from request and from database) and two outputs (to database and to Response)

Answer (score 0):

You should check DRF [documentation on custom fields](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#custom-fields)

As stated, to return a custom object, you have to define the `.to_representation()` method.

The example from the docs:

```
class ClassNameField(serializers.Field):
    def get_attribute(self, obj):
        # We pass the object instance onto `to_representation`,
        # not just the field attribute.
        return obj

    def to_representation(self, obj):
        """
        Serialize the object's class name.
        """
        return obj.__class__.__name__
```

Comment: It's necessary to access the input value in addition to `obj` in order to determine what the representation should be.